# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 43.5 GiB for an array with shape (5844379795,) and data type int64

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and I am trying to update one column :

**Dataframe:**

[image]

I would like to update the last column **IsFraudsterStatus**.

**My Code:**

```
df= pd.concat(chunk_list,)
    def expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, col_name):
        t = pd.merge(no_fraud, fraud, on=col_name)
        if len(t):
            df.loc[df.ID.isin(t.ID_x), "IsFraudsterStatus"] = 1
            return True
        return False
    while True:
        added_fraud = False
        fraud = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 1]
        no_fraud = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 0]
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "DeviceId")
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "Email")
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "MobileNo")
        if not added_fraud:
            break
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Your error message is self-explanatory and it says that you don't have enough Memory left to perform your desired action. Why don't you use [dask](https://dask.org/) to handle your large dataset?

Comment: @RezaBehzadpour Hmm, I thought that pandas can deal with 3 million rows.

Comment: The problem with `pandas` is that it loads everything into memory, hence making it difficult (sometimes impossible) to work with large datasets. But `dask` doesn't load your entire dataset into memory and loads things when needed. They also share very similar API (interface), so you would feel like home when you work with `dask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Dask](https://dask.org/) has solved all the "Memory Error" problems.